# Difference meaning :having ving vs having p.p

Tags: grammar

Having learning English in three months, Jovovich grabbed the attention of photographer, Richard Avedon.

Having learnt English in three months, Jovovich grabbed the attention of photographer, Richard Avedon.

Would you kindly elaborate their differences?

Source:

www.myfdb.com/people/2645-milla-jovovich]https://www.myfdb.com/people/2645-milla-jovovich

Comment: `Having learning ` is not grammatical in this sentence, that is the main difference .

Answer (score 2):

'Having learned' or 'having learnt' are both grammatically correct.

'Having learning' is not correct in this context, although it could be correct if 'learning' is used as a noun, meaning 'education', as in 'Having learning, she was able to master English in a few months', but it's a somewhat contrived example.

In short, the form of the passage in the link you gave contradicts the content.